# Adding elements to an object with multiple properties

Tags: javascript, object

Im pretty new working with objects, and I just cant seem to get this to work no matter how I try it.

My idea is that I want to treat printObj just like a database-table and then keep adding "records" to it.  (then later "updating" the "records" and eventually loop thru all rendering them in an HTML result)

But I keep getting **Uncaught TypeError: printObj.push is not a function**

```
var printObj = new Object();

printObj.push({
    property: 'WAT-606',
    project: 'Wong Amat Tower',
    year: 2017,
    month: 1,
    bookedPct: 52
});

for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    var addObj = new Object();
    addObj["property"] = 'WAT-606';
    addObj["project"] = 'Wong Amat Tower';
    addObj["year"] = 2017;
    addObj["month"] = 1;
    addObj["bookedPct"] = 52+i;
    printObj.push(addObj);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do `push`. It is for `Arrays`. Directly create with properties, like

```
var printObj = {
    property: 'WAT-606',
    project: 'Wong Amat Tower',
    year: 2017,
    month: 1,
    bookedPct: 52
}
```

If you want to add additional, do like

```
printObj.newProp = val;
```

First, learn about `Objects` completely. This [site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) will help you

Comment: Thanks for the link - now I see the difference.  Great site btw!!

Answer (score 1):

You are really looking for an array, which you create like this:

```js
var printArr = [];

printArr.push({
    property: 'WAT-606',
    project: 'Wong Amat Tower',
    year: 2017,
    month: 1,
    bookedPct: 52
});

for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    var addObj = {};
    addObj.property = 'WAT-606';
    addObj.project = 'Wong Amat Tower';
    addObj.year = 2017;
    addObj.month = 1;
    addObj.bookedPct = 52+i;
    printArr.push(addObj);
}

console.log(printArr);
```

Comment: Ahhh thanks - I need to study objects some more, keep confusing the two :)